# How to refresh LunarVim after Git pull or Git checkout?

Tags: lua, refresh, neovim, lunarvim

Does anyone know how to refresh LunarVim after a Git pull or a Git checkout? I keep working around this by closing and reopening LunarVim, which is completely wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh"?

Comment: So, when you git clone, some files change and usualy it is a problem

Comment: Do you want to refresh a file that you are currently editing in your buffer, or refresh a file that affects the configuration of Neovim?

Comment: Well, imagine using TMUX and you have split your window horizontally.
I usually have lubarvim in upper half and terminal in a bottom part of a window. 

While Lunarvim is still open, I do `git pull` so the content of the files was changed.

I was looking for some easy way to "refresh" all buffers in LunarVim to reflect the changes when git pull

Answer (score 0):

```
vim.o.autoread = true
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ 'CursorHold', 
'CursorHoldI', 'FocusGained' }, {
      command = "if mode() != 'c' | 
      checktime | endif",
      pattern = { '*' },
})
```

You can create autocmd like this and it will change buffer if file changed in disk like git pull